# How to check for linearity of a transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I check the linearity of the transformation 
$$
T: F \to \mathbb{R} \quad T(x) = \int\limits_0^1 e^{x(t)}\,dt
$$

Comment: Show that $T(x+\lambda y)=T(x)+\lambda T(y)$ for all $x,y \in F$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: what is $F$ in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try it on a linear combination:
$$
T(\alpha x + \beta y) = \int\limits_0^1 e^{\alpha x(t) + \beta y(t)} \, dt 
\overset{!}{=} \alpha T(x) + \beta T(y) \quad (x, y \in F, \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R})
$$
where the equation to prove is marked by an exclamation mark $(!)$.

So this means
$$
\int\limits_0^1 e^{\alpha x(t) + \beta y(t)} \, dt 
\overset{!}{=}
\alpha \int\limits_0^1 e^{x(t)} \, dt 
+
\beta \int\limits_0^1 e^{y(t)} \, dt 
$$
choosing the constant functions $x(t) = y(t) = 0$ this would mean
$$
\int\limits_0^1 e^0 \, dt 
\overset{!}{=}
\alpha \int\limits_0^1 e^{0} \, dt 
+
\beta \int\limits_0^1 e^{0} \, dt \iff
1
\overset{!}{=}
\alpha + \beta 
$$
which is not true in general, e.g. for $\alpha = \beta = 0$.
This makes sense as a linear transformation should map $0$ to $0$, which it does not.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did it and got that it is linear, and wanted to make sure that's correct. I can't learn with math without seeing examples and haven't been getting them in my class on this material.

Comment: @DavidScidmore I think it is not linear, let me try.